# Subquery returned more than one value, Variables not allowed are =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql-server

Getting error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Please help me with this query:

```
DECLARE @TYPENAME varchar(20) = 'Hardness';
DECLARE @MODEL varchar(20) = 'LEEB';
DECLARE @SPECIFICATION varchar(20) = 'Other';
DECLARE @EQUIPMENT varchar(20) = 'Phase II Model: PHT-18 00 S/N: PHO109112815';

BEGIN

SELECT 
    Document.TypeName
    ,Document.CreatedDateTime
    ,QuestionType.SequenceNumber
    ,QuestionType.ValueType
    ,QuestionType.NAME
    ,Answer.ValueAsString
    ,Answer.ValueAsNumber
    ,Answer.ValueAsDateTime
    ,Person.FamilyName
    ,Person.GivenName
    ,QuestionType.AnswerType
    ,Media.Media
FROM 
    Document (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    DocumentType (NOLOCK) ON Document.DocumentTypeGuid = DocumentType.Guid
INNER JOIN 
    Answer (NOLOCK) ON Document.Guid = Answer.ParentDocumentGuid
INNER JOIN 
    QuestionType (NOLOCK) ON Answer.QuestionTypeGuid = QuestionType.Guid
LEFT JOIN 
    Media (NOLOCK) on Media.ParentGuid = Answer.Guid
LEFT JOIN 
    Person (NOLOCK) ON Document.CreatedBySystemUserGuid = Person.Guid
WHERE
    DocumentType.BonIdentifier = @TYPENAME 
    AND Document.Guid IN (CASE  
                             WHEN @TYPENAME = 'Hardness'
                                THEN (SELECT hrd.[DocumentGuid] 
                                      FROM [dbo].[Hardness] hrd
                                      WHERE (@MODEL IS NULL OR REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[HardnessType]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@MODEL),' ','')+'%')
                                        AND (@SPECIFICATION IS NULL OR (REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[RockwellTestMethod]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'
   OR  REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[LEEBTestMethod]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'
   OR  REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[TelebrinellerTestMethod]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'
   ))
   AND (@EQUIPMENT IS NULL OR (REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[RockwellEquipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'
   OR  REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[LEEBEquipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'
   OR  REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[TelebrinellerEquipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'
   ))
  )
 ELSE 
  (
     SELECT mh.[DocumentGuid] from [dbo].[MicroHardness] mh
     WHERE
     (@MODEL IS NULL OR REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[HardnessType]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@MODEL),' ','')+'%')
     AND (@SPECIFICATION IS NULL OR (REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[WT Test Method]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'
     OR  REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[BM Test Method]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'     
     ))
     AND (@EQUIPMENT IS NULL OR (REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[WT Equipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'
     OR  REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[BM Equipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'     
     ))
  )
END
)
    AND QuestionType.AnswerType NOT IN ('Single Pick List', 'Multi-Pick List')
    AND QuestionType.AnswerType <> 'Summary'
    AND QuestionType.AnswerType <> 'Informational'
    AND Document.Active = 1
ORDER BY 
    Document.CreatedDateTime, QuestionType.SequenceNumber;

END
```

Comment: The problem may be in the `CASE` expressions, where the subqueries return more than one value.  You need to fix the logic there.

Comment: I don't think  that @TimBiegeleisen is right. The inner selects are expected to return one or more values (see the condition `...AND Document.Guid in...`). I would suggest you re-arrange your inner queries into a more readable layout and check parenthesis.

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is working fine @Zohar Peled but it degrades the performance, so I myself found out the solution, separating entire query through condition find below,

```
DECLARE @TYPENAME varchar(20) = 'MicroHardness';
DECLARE @MODEL varchar(20) = 'Wilson Tukon';
DECLARE @SPECIFICATION varchar(20) = 'ASTME 384';
DECLARE @EQUIPMENT varchar(20) = '300 BM/DF, S/N: 83180-483';

BEGIN

IF(@TYPENAME = 'Hardness')

SELECT 
    Document.Guid,
    Document.TypeName
    ,Document.CreatedDateTime
    ,QuestionType.SequenceNumber
    ,QuestionType.ValueType
    ,QuestionType.NAME
    ,Answer.ValueAsString
    ,Answer.ValueAsNumber
    ,Answer.ValueAsDateTime
    ,Person.FamilyName
    ,Person.GivenName
    ,QuestionType.AnswerType
    ,Media.Media
FROM Document (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN DocumentType (NOLOCK) ON Document.DocumentTypeGuid = DocumentType.Guid
INNER JOIN Answer (NOLOCK) ON Document.Guid = Answer.ParentDocumentGuid
INNER JOIN QuestionType (NOLOCK) ON Answer.QuestionTypeGuid = QuestionType.Guid
LEFT JOIN Media (NOLOCK) on Media.ParentGuid = Answer.Guid
LEFT JOIN Person (NOLOCK) ON Document.CreatedBySystemUserGuid = Person.Guid
WHERE
DocumentType.BonIdentifier = @TYPENAME AND Document.Guid in
(
   SELECT hrd.[DocumentGuid] from [dbo].[Hardness] hrd
   WHERE
   (@MODEL IS NULL OR REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[HardnessType]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@MODEL),' ','')+'%')
   AND (@SPECIFICATION IS NULL OR (REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[RockwellTestMethod]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'
   OR  REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[LEEBTestMethod]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'
   OR  REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[TelebrinellerTestMethod]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'
   ))
   AND (@EQUIPMENT IS NULL OR (REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[RockwellEquipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'
   OR  REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[LEEBEquipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'
   OR  REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[TelebrinellerEquipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'
   ))
)
AND QuestionType.AnswerType not in ('Single Pick List', 'Multi-Pick List')
AND QuestionType.AnswerType <> 'Summary'
AND QuestionType.AnswerType <> 'Informational'
AND Document.Active = 1
ORDER BY Document.CreatedDateTime, QuestionType.SequenceNumber;

ELSE IF(@TYPENAME = 'MicroHardness')

SELECT 
    Document.Guid,
    Document.TypeName
    ,Document.CreatedDateTime
    ,QuestionType.SequenceNumber
    ,QuestionType.ValueType
    ,QuestionType.NAME
    ,Answer.ValueAsString
    ,Answer.ValueAsNumber
    ,Answer.ValueAsDateTime
    ,Person.FamilyName
    ,Person.GivenName
    ,QuestionType.AnswerType
    ,Media.Media
FROM Document (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN DocumentType (NOLOCK) ON Document.DocumentTypeGuid = DocumentType.Guid
INNER JOIN Answer (NOLOCK) ON Document.Guid = Answer.ParentDocumentGuid
INNER JOIN QuestionType (NOLOCK) ON Answer.QuestionTypeGuid = QuestionType.Guid
LEFT JOIN Media (NOLOCK) on Media.ParentGuid = Answer.Guid
LEFT JOIN Person (NOLOCK) ON Document.CreatedBySystemUserGuid = Person.Guid
WHERE
DocumentType.BonIdentifier = @TYPENAME AND Document.Guid in
(
   SELECT mh.[DocumentGuid] from [dbo].[MicroHardness] mh
     WHERE
     (@MODEL IS NULL OR REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[HardnessType]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@MODEL),' ','')+'%')
     AND (@SPECIFICATION IS NULL OR (REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[WT Test Method]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'
     OR  REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[BM Test Method]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'     
     ))
     AND (@EQUIPMENT IS NULL OR (REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[WT Equipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'
     OR  REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[BM Equipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'     
     ))
)
AND QuestionType.AnswerType not in ('Single Pick List', 'Multi-Pick List')
AND QuestionType.AnswerType <> 'Summary'
AND QuestionType.AnswerType <> 'Informational'
AND Document.Active = 1
ORDER BY Document.CreatedDateTime, QuestionType.SequenceNumber;

END
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure @TimBiegeleisen is correct, but just didn't explain that good. I think that the problem here is the use of `case`. Instead of `case`, I would simply use `or`:

(Note: You might get a syntax error due to a misplaced parenthasis, there where so many of them I kinda got lost)

```
SELECT 
    Document.TypeName
    ,Document.CreatedDateTime
    ,QuestionType.SequenceNumber
    ,QuestionType.ValueType
    ,QuestionType.NAME
    ,Answer.ValueAsString
    ,Answer.ValueAsNumber
    ,Answer.ValueAsDateTime
    ,Person.FamilyName
    ,Person.GivenName
    ,QuestionType.AnswerType
    ,Media.Media
FROM 
    Document (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    DocumentType (NOLOCK) ON Document.DocumentTypeGuid = DocumentType.Guid
INNER JOIN 
    Answer (NOLOCK) ON Document.Guid = Answer.ParentDocumentGuid
INNER JOIN 
    QuestionType (NOLOCK) ON Answer.QuestionTypeGuid = QuestionType.Guid
LEFT JOIN 
    Media (NOLOCK) on Media.ParentGuid = Answer.Guid
LEFT JOIN 
    Person (NOLOCK) ON Document.CreatedBySystemUserGuid = Person.Guid
WHERE
    DocumentType.BonIdentifier = @TYPENAME 
    AND 
    (
    ( 
        @TYPENAME = 'Hardness'
        AND Document.Guid IN ((SELECT hrd.[DocumentGuid] 
                                      FROM [dbo].[Hardness] hrd
                                      WHERE (@MODEL IS NULL OR REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[HardnessType]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@MODEL),' ','')+'%')
                                        AND (@SPECIFICATION IS NULL OR (REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[RockwellTestMethod]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'
   OR  REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[LEEBTestMethod]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'
   OR  REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[TelebrinellerTestMethod]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'
   ))
   AND (@EQUIPMENT IS NULL OR (REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[RockwellEquipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'
   OR  REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[LEEBEquipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'
   OR  REPLACE(LOWER(hrd.[TelebrinellerEquipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'
   ))
  )
   OR 
  (
      @TYPENAME <> 'Hardness'
      AND

  (
     SELECT mh.[DocumentGuid] from [dbo].[MicroHardness] mh
     WHERE
     (@MODEL IS NULL OR REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[HardnessType]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@MODEL),' ','')+'%')
     AND (@SPECIFICATION IS NULL OR (REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[WT Test Method]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'
     OR  REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[BM Test Method]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@SPECIFICATION),' ','')+'%'     
     ))
     AND (@EQUIPMENT IS NULL OR (REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[WT Equipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'
     OR  REPLACE(LOWER(mh.[BM Equipment]),' ','') LIKE '%'+REPLACE(LOWER(@EQUIPMENT),' ','')+'%'     
     ))
  )

)
    AND QuestionType.AnswerType NOT IN ('Single Pick List', 'Multi-Pick List')
    AND QuestionType.AnswerType <> 'Summary'
    AND QuestionType.AnswerType <> 'Informational'
    AND Document.Active = 1
ORDER BY 
    Document.CreatedDateTime, QuestionType.SequenceNumber;
```